# Appending a list with a list assigned to variable gives output of multiple times the same final version of the variable

Tags: python, list, variables, append

For the 'Queens Problem'(position 8 queens on a chess board so that none of them attack each other) I wrote a programm to display all possible solutions as a list. The list has 8 positions, each of them represent an x coordinate of the chess board. The code works fine but at the end i would like to make another list, containing all the lists with possible solutions for the problem. Here the problem arises: The list of solutions only shows the final solution multiple times. I think this is because the list take the variable (here b) and appends it and then when i print it it just prints the final solution for b, as it has changed. How can I work around this?

I added a part of the code that shows the general setup:
b is a list with 8 elements, representing the chess board.
sol should be the list that contains all of the possible solutions

```
for b[0] in r8:
    for b[1] in r8:
        if check(1) == True and checkdi(1) == True:
            for b[2] in r8:
                if check(2) == True and checkdi(2) == True:
                    for b[3] in r8:
                        if check(3) == True and checkdi(3) == True:
                            for b[4] in r8:
                                if check(4) == True and checkdi(4) == True:
                                    for b[5] in r8:
                                        if check(5) == True and checkdi(5) == True:
                                            for b[6] in r8:
                                                if check(6) == True and checkdi(6) == True:
                                                    for b[7] in r8:
                                                        if check(7) == True and checkdi(7) == True:
                                                            sol.append(b)
                                                            print(sol)
                                                            print(b)
```

The solutions it prints with print(b) are all fine, so the code is working just fine, I just need help with creating a list of all possible solutions

This is my first post here, if there is anything I can do better on my posts please let me know aswell.

Comment: What do you think `for b[0]` etc would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using

```
import copy
sol.append(copy.deepcopy(b))
```

and maybe just print sol where the loops are done. here i am assuming you initialized sol as `sol = []` before the loop.